# How to collect images with a Whatsapp bot using Twilio

Tags: twilio

I've created a Whatsapp chat bot that collects various user information but I am unable to collect an image that a user sends. How can I do this? Is it a matter of using the right Field type, which I've tried doing but none of the default field's apply to images? Please help if anyone knows of a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Heyooo.  Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

If a User sends an image via Whatsapp the image URL will be available in the sent webhook. You can have a look at the payload the webhook includes:

```
body: { 
  MediaContentType0: 'image/jpeg',
  SmsMessageSid: 'MM9...',
  NumMedia: '1',
  SmsSid: 'MM9...',
  SmsStatus: 'received',
  Body: '',
  To: 'whatsapp:+141...',
  NumSegments: '1',
  MessageSid: 'MM9bc...',
  AccountSid: 'ACa34...',
  From: 'whatsapp:+49176...',
  MediaUrl0: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACa34bb5d3c305d08ae1308786f4d79b72/Messages/MM9bc3...',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01'
}
```

You'll find the `NumMedia` and `MediaUrl0` property which includes the URL of the sent image. You can then download these images and do whatever you like with them.

To retrieve the image after the message and webhook were sent you can have a look at [the MediaResource Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource). You can fetch media also programmatically with something along the following lines:

```
client.messages('MM...')
      .media('ME...')
      .fetch()
      .then(media => console.log(media.contentType));
```

In case you're using [Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio) you can have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/virtual-photo-booth-twilio-whatsapp-cloudinary) which handles Whatsapp Media with a fun use case.

---

Let me know if that helps.

*(It's hard to give more advice because I'm not sure what you're trying to do.)*